# Foundation - align nested divs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

Learning responsive design and also Zurb foundation.

http://jsfiddle.net/CA669/1312/

The 2 inner divs, green and red are not responsive. The current design just shows, how they have to be, on a large screen. What should be done to make this responsive.
Also, Im not sure what's the best way to show the red div on smaller screens.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
        <div class="row fullWidth">
            <div class="twelve columns banner">
              <div class="logo">
                   Median Solutions</div>
              <div class="settings">
                   Hello Admin &nbsp;&nbsp;|
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;<a>Change Password</a>
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a>Logout</a>
              </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS :**

```
*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.fullWidth
{
  width:100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: initial;
}
.banner
{
    background:lightgray;
    height:60px;
}
.logo
{
    color:White;
    font-size:20px; 
    line-height:60px;    
    width:190px;
    border:1px solid green;
    float:left;   
}
.settings
{
    float:right;
    line-height:60px;
    color:White;
    width:310px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
 @media all and (max-width: 510px) 
 {
  .banner{height:auto; text-align:center;}
  .settings,
  .logo{float:none; display:inline-block;}
 }
```

EDIT:

looks like this now at a certain width:

[image]

Comment: best solution: replace it on smaller screens with an Dropdown

Comment: What version of Foundation are you using? As the grid classes are different in recent version.

Answer (score 0):

As Adrian mentioned, a dropdown would be best, but you can also do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/CA669/1314/

```
@media all and (max-width: 510px) {
    .banner{height:auto; text-align:center;}
    .settings,
    .logo{float:none; display:inline-block;}
}
```

Comment: I have updated a snap of what it looks now at a certain length. Dont think it is responsive is it. The two divs should also have the foundation classes like row/columns, is what I think...but dont know how?

Comment: If you throw my media query at the bottom of your css file it should fix your issue.

Comment: its there as suggested.

Comment: Looks like the styles aren't being applied, you might have to target the classes deeper. Is there a way you could post some more of the code?

Comment: Infact, that is all the code I have. Just started the page. So that is all there is... The other piece in pic was a test and is not there now. Are you using foundation. If you try the code in browser, you can see that is not at all good looking